# What's causing this np.array data type error, and what's the fix?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on an image output project-- I can't figure out what the problem specific to this line is: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 input_array[i].append(np.array(Image.fromarray(img_input).resize(float(g_scale), resample=Image.BICUBIC)))

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

The "cannot handle this data type" was manually written in case an error like this happened. I searched up multiple possibilities as to the problem with the Image.fromarray line and couldn't narrow it down to this specific line's needs. Could appreciate any help!

Here's a more full view of the for loop being used, it's essentially testing the network:

```
  for i, gscale in enumerate(gscales):
            if float(g_scale) == 1:
                input_array[i].append(img_input)
            else:
                input_array[i].append(np.array(Image.fromarray(img_input).resize(float(g_scale), resample=Image.BICUBIC)))

            output_array[i].append(eval_model.predict_on_batch(input_array[i][-1]))
```

Comment: Assuming error was in `Image.fromarray(img_input)` you could remove the other stuff as uneeded for this question. Then focus on `img_input` - can you trim your data to something small enough to post but still shows the problem?

Comment: Another option is to use a debugger like `pdb` or your favorite IDE. Breakpoint the line and look at the data. You could even edit that file and add prints into the code that raises the error to get more information on what it is. That's an advantage of source based languages, you can fiddle with them at will.

Comment: I will check out a debugger as you recommended, thanks! I cut out the unnecessary stuff and added a more full picture of the for loop it was contained in. Would love any advice.

Comment: Usually we ask for the full traceback. And with that  information about the variables involved - especially shape and dtype.  Be on the look out for object dtype resulting from combining arrays with differing shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your editor, it might be because you used g_scale rather than gscale inside the for loop. It could have skipped the variable name error and instead pick up on the error from the line after else.